# SQL injection in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is this all to stop SQL injection in Drupal?

```
db_query('INSERT INTO {tablename} (field1, field2) VALUES ("%s", "%s")', $field1, $field2);
```

Comment: AAAAAAH, not the answer I wanted. What more? :(

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Don't use double-quotes for string literal delimiters, that's a non-standard MySQL feature. By using that you're defeating the cross-database purpose of the `db_` functions. ANSI standard (that also works on MySQL) is single quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your question "Is this all I need to do to stop SQL injection in Drupal?"

The answer is "Almost, but not quite."

```
db_query("INSERT INTO {tablename} (field1, field2) VALUES ('%s', '%s')", 
         $field1, $field2);
```

Single quotes are more standard for quoting values in SQL.

Alternately, if you've defined tablename table via hook_schema, you can use drupal_write_record instead, as the other answer states.  The advantage of drupal_write_record is that you don't have to deal with any sql, you just do this:

```
$tablename = array('field1' => $field1, 'field2' => $field2);
drupal_write_record('tablename', $tablename);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You mean `$field1 $field2` can be raw $POST data not sanitized at all by me? Is it fine? Drupal will just take care of it all?

Comment: They can be raw $_POST data, yes.  I would suggest using the form api, which would then allow you to get the data out of $form_state['values'] instead, but drupal's code will handle any sort of raw data.  If the values are fixed-length char/varchar fields, I'd recommend checking the string length before doing the insert anyway, because it's a good practice.

Answer (score 5):

You can use parameters, [as described in the documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/db_query).

However, you should call the [`drupal_write_record` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_write_record/6) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using drupal_write_record() function instead of SQL instructions, as SLaks pointed before.